# List all tables in a DB using SQLite

Tags: sqlite

I can't seem to find documentation (that I understand) on how to list all tables in a database. I've tried the following:

```
SELECT * FROM .table;
SELECT * FROM .tab;
SELECT * FROM .db;
SELECT * FROM world.db;
```

None of them worked. I'm just learning SQL, so forgive my ignorance.  :0)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table'
```

Comment: Thanks! I was just about to edit my post to add
SELECT * FROM world.sqlite_master WHERE type='table';
to the queries I tried. looks like I had too much info in mine.

Answer (score 8):

If you are in interactive mode, you can use this:

```
.tables
```

Another method with extra information:

```
.schema
```

https://sqlite.org/cli.html#querying_the_database_schema